# Is there a development environment 'checklist' I can run through before starting to code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, development-environment

I am following Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, and have gone through setting up my Development Environment.

I want to quickly check I have everything in order i.e. RVM, Ruby, Rails, Git, etc. all installed in the right place and correctly configured.

If you were picking up a beginner's computer and wanted to understand their development environment and spot anything missing (before running into errors later on), is there a hygiene checklist you go through?

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: "How can I do this?" - write automated health checks/tests.

Comment: the real question you should be asking is ["vim or Emacs?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editor_war)

Comment: @bsoist Since the answer is always Emacs it's not really a question ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton oh boy, sorry I brought it uo! :)

Comment: Seriously @max_jf5, just start writing code. You'll figure out what you might have missed later.

Comment: Thanks bsoist - I'll take your advice

Answer (score 0):

Michael hartls tutorial explains well what you need, but for a short list:

> Curl

is needed to get RVM and to test HTTP requests. You will need it to install some requirements also.

> Git:

You need it during the tutorial, and to get some gems directly from github.

> Any JS platform:

I've choosen **NODEJS** because it's the easiest one to install, but you can use any of your like: rubyracer, v8...

> Ruby interpreter:

Then Install a ruby version. I've always install the last one as default and then install the ones needed in the project.

```
The gems:
```

If you are using Ruby > 2.0 install byebug if not install debugger. And rails, the last version as well. If you are following a tutorial install other version.

Any editor:

If you want to learn I recommend you **VIM**, as you will get used to develop and will learn a nice editor. Learning a nice command line editor is allways payed. So don't be afraid. You can learn sublime or gedit at any moment, but learning VIM is hardest, so start now.

```
Then databases.
```

Install whichever you want:

```
MySQL.
PostgreSQL
SQlite
Or mongo, just to practice.
```

that should be enough to start the tutorial.